# How to use java.sql.Array with Spring

Tags: java, sql, arrays, postgresql, spring-boot

I'm trying to make a Spring application and I've hit a snag.

Here's my model class:

```
@Entity
@Component
public class Theater {
    
    @Id
    private int theaterId;
    private Array theaterNumbers;
    private String theaterLoc;
    
    public Theater(Array theaterNumbers, String theaterLoc) {
        super();
        this.theaterNumbers = theaterNumbers;
        this.theaterLoc = theaterLoc;
    }

    public int getTheaterId() {
        return theaterId;
    }

    public void setTheaterId(int theaterId) {
        this.theaterId = theaterId;
    }

    
    public Array getTheaterNumbers() {
        return theaterNumbers;
    }

    public void setTheaterNumbers(Array theaterNumbers) {
        this.theaterNumbers = theaterNumbers;
    }

    public String getTheaterLoc() {
        return theaterLoc;
    }

    public void setTheaterLoc(String theaterLoc) {
        this.theaterLoc = theaterLoc;
    }
```

This is the error I'm receiving:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.sql.Array, at table: theater, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(theater_numbers)]
```

I'm not sure where to start. I've looked around and haven't found anyone with a similar problem. I'm using Array because I have an array in my postgres db. java.sql.Array to be precise.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`Array` is a low-level class that you shouldn't interact with.

Use `List<String>` instead.

Comment: Will that work with my array in the database? Will I be able to store it in a List?

Comment: Depends, but in general `List`s are supported.